# SimpleForm: Always Label Before Element and Without Cutting off Text

Tags: sapui5

As you can see in the image below, the labels are cut off and part of the text is replaced with ellipsis (`...`). I want to have a [SimpleForm](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm) that is always (whatever the screen size or DOM with available) showing the [Label](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Label) left from the text (as shown in the screenshot), but I want the full label to be visible.

[image: Screenshot]

```
<f:SimpleForm
  editable="false"
  layout="GridLayout"
  title="Title"
  labelSpanXL="12"
  labelSpanL="12"
  labelSpanM="12"
  labelSpanS="12"
  adjustLabelSpan="true"
  emptySpanXL="8"
  emptySpanL="8"
  emptySpanM="8"
  emptySpanS="8"
  columnsXL="5"
  columnsL="5"
  columnsM="5"
  singleContainerFullSize="true">
  <f:content>
    <Label text="LABEL VERY LONG LABEL IS LONG"/>
    <Text text="TEXT"/>
  </f:content>
</f:SimpleForm>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of UI5 version 1.50, you can enable [`wrapping`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Label/methods/setWrapping) in Label so that it doesn't get cut off.

[image: sap.m.Label wrapping]

---

Update: And [as of version 1.54](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/2ed9e8321e5eb361c030594119845cd355b1cc4c/src/sap.m/test/sap/m/relnotes/changes-1.54.json#L989-L994), the wrapping is [automatically enabled](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/75b6b7b99024549f601219d3474f051c77d6f128) in [(Simple)Form](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.layout.form.Form)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [FlexBox](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.FlexBox.html) in your `<f:content>`.

```
<f:content>
    <FlexBox width="100%" wrap="Wrap">
        <HBox width="100%" class="sapUiTinyMarginBottom">
            <VBox class="sapUiTinyMarginEnd">
                <Label text="LABEL VERY LONG LABEL IS LONG"/>
            </VBox>
            <VBox>
                <Text text="TEXT"/>
            </VBox>
        </HBox>
        <HBox width="100%">
            <VBox class="sapUiTinyMarginEnd">
                <Label text="SECOND LABEL VERY LONG LABEL IS LONG"/>
            </VBox>
            <VBox>
                <Text text="SECOND TEXT"/>
            </VBox>
        </HBox>
    </FlexBox>
</f:content>
```